# Whats the name of the C# feature that allows you to implicitly consider a List<ChildClass> as a List<ParentClass>

Tags: c#

It is relevant to a technical discussion I'm participating in.

Comment: There is no such feature, you can add a `ParentClass` to `List<ParentClass>` but not to `List<ChildClass>` and so it is not possible to consider `List<ChildClass>` as a `List<ParentClass>`. You can, however, consider a sequence of `ChildClass` as a sequence of `ParentClass`. The term for this is covariance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're talking about [*generic covariance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) - but it doesn't apply to `List<T>`, which is *invariant*.

It *does* apply to `IEnumerable<T>` though:

```
IEnumerable<ChildClass> children = new List<ChildClass>();
IEnumerable<ParentClass> parents = children;
```

Comment: Note: It doesn't apply to `List<T>` because you both put things **in** and get things **out**. It can apply to `IEnumerable<T>` because you're only getting things out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [Covariance and Contravariance.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)